# What are "legal events" as listed on Google Patents?

Tags: google-patents, us8775248

In reference to the patent: [US8775248](https://www.google.com/patents/US8775248)

At the bottom of this page there are two Legal Events. What do they mean in this context?

At the time of writing, the legal events are as follows:

> #### Mar 27, 2013 -- Assignment
>
> Owner name: EXPONENTIAL INTERACTIVE, INC., CALIFORNIA
>
> Free format text: ASSIGNMENT OF ASSIGNORS INTEREST;ASSIGNORS:SALDANHA, ALEXANDER;BERMAN, RON;VUMMARAO, KESHORE;SIGNING DATES FROM 20130312 TO 20130313;REEL/FRAME:030099/0179
>
> #### Mar 12, 2014 -- Assignment
>
> Owner name: ABAKUS, INC., CALIFORNIA
>
> Free format text: ASSIGNMENT OF ASSIGNORS INTEREST;ASSIGNOR:EXPONENTIAL INTERACTIVE INC.;REEL/FRAME:032420/0386
>
> Effective date: 20131213

Answer (score 2):

The legal events are assignments that transfer of ownership of the patent.  In this case the inventors assigned their ownership to Exponential Interactive and later Exponential Interactive assigned its ownership to Abakus.  The current owner is Abakus.